# Navigate Up to Parent Activity from Notification

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform, push-notification

My question is that I have two activities, Activity A and Activity B. Activity A is the main activity, Activity B is only accessible by touching a notification.

I need to be able to touch a notification, which will open Activity B. After the user is finished with Activity B, they can press the back button or finish Activity B. When Activity B closes, Activity A should be shown. Currently, I close Activity A (which closes the entire app) and receive a push notification. I select the push notification which opens Activity B. When I close Activity B, Activity A is not shown and the entire app closes. I want Activity A to be there after finishing Activity B.

I am using Parse SDK notifications. In my custom ParsePushBroadcastReceiver I have the following code

```
public class MyReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver 
{
  @Override
  public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {        

    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

I have it listed in the Android Manifest. My notification activity in manifest is

```
<activity
        android:name=".NotificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity"/>

</activity>
```

In my notification activity I have the following code in onBackPressed

```
public class NotificationActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{...
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() 
   {
      if(NavUtils.getParentActivityName(this) != null)
      {
        Log.d(Constants.NAVIGATION_DEBUG, "Get Parent Activity NOT NULL"); 

        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); 
      }
      else
      {
        Log.d(Constants.NAVIGATION_DEBUG, "Get Parent Activity NULL"); 

        super.onBackPressed();
      } 
     }
...}
```

Surprisely, in the logs it states that it is NOT NULL, however it doesn't navigate back to Activity A if the app was closed prior to pressing the notification. Instead the app closes. I want Activity A to show whether the app was closed when the notification was pressed or whether the app is open. THANKS!

Comment: Have a look at shouldUpRecreateTask , may be it can help creating task stack if activity is not in your task.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#shouldUpRecreateTask(android.app.Activity, android.content.Intent)

Comment: Mohammad - I would look at this, but I don't see how this will help me with the problem that I have. What I want is to open a notification activity, and when the user exits that activity then the home activity should be there, before the notification activity. Essentially there are two activities, Activity A and B. A is the MAIN activity, whereas B is solely for notifications. Pressing a notification should show the user Activity B without showing the user Activity A at all. When the user is done with Activity B, it closes and navigates back to Activity A.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following method: put some boolean extra in your intent, and then start **MainActivity**. That extra will be the indicator of **NotificationActivity** start.

```
public class MyReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver 
{
  @Override
  public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) 
  {        

    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    i.putExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION", true);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(i);
  }
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity's` `onCreate()` method, do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION", false)) {
            startActivity(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
        }
    } 
    // other initialization code
    ...
...
}
```

Then you don't need to override `onBackPressed` in your `NotificationActivity`.

Comment: If I did this I would be able to navigate back to Activity A, but it would clearly show two activities starting back to back after pressing the notification button. That would look horrible.

Comment: What if you move `if` statement **before** `setContentView` ?

Comment: That is not a possible solution since that would ONLY open one Activity, and I wouldn't have a previous activity to navigate back to.

Answer (score 0):

for the temporary solution, you must start  your MainActivity onBackPress() of NotificationActivity..

Comment: This doesn't give the "look" of going backwards. Instead it looks like I am going deeper (forwards) into the app. I could finish Activity B and start Activity A from onBackPress() but this may cause the user to think that if they press the back button from Activity A they will somehow go backwards to Activity B! On Yahoo app for android if a Breaking news is available you receive a notification. After reading the breaking new you can then press the back button or home button on the action bar and it will take you BACKWARDS to a previous activity, regardless if the Yahoo! app is opened or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just so everyone else who is running into this problem will have a solution which works I will post my solution to this migraine problem. The way I solved this problem is by using Fragments.

Explanation: In the activity oncreate I check the Intent to see if the user is in the application due to selecting a notification. If so I can transition to the notification fragment, if not I can transition to the main fragment. After the user is finished with the notification fragment the user will either press the back key on their phone, or press the back arrow in the ActionBar, so the developer has to handle both of those situations.

To handle the back button on the phone simply override onbackpressed in your activity and check to see if the user is in the notification fragment, if so then smoothly transition to your main fragment, without keeping the notification fragment in the backstack.

To handle the back button in the actionbar, override onoptionsselected in your fragment and when the user presses the back button (android.R.id.home) you simply smoothly transition to your mainfragment.

If you are also handling overriding your activity onnewintent, simply pass in a boolean to your fragment letting your notification fragment know whether it has been opened from onnewintent or oncreate from your activity.

If your notification fragment is opened from onnewintent, you wouldn't want to transition to your mainfragment, since your mainfragment would already be open and in the backstack. So you would simply POP the fragments backstack, or let the android system automatically handle proper navigation.

It's a lot of work, but it is a solution, **and in theory this solution should work across all Android API's from GINGERBREAD - LOLLIPOP**, as long as the user is using Fragments, and the user is using a custom animation to transition between fragments.

The key is using a custom fragment transition from the notification fragment back to the main fragment ( or in the case of onnewintent, whatever fragment came before it) to give the impression that the user is going BACKWARDS from notification fragment to main fragment. If anyone else comes with a better solution... I am all ears.

Answer (score -1):

Use TaskStackBuilder in Android its the same you need.